# Capybara-webkit with jruby

Tags: capybara, jrubyonrails

I am working on moving our celerity based integration tests to capybara-webkit.
The documentation provided on git-hub (https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) for capybara-webkit was helpful but i am unable to run my tests, ending up with error for jruby:

NotImplementedError: fork is not available on this platform
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1792:in `fork'

Is there a way I can get capybara-webkit work with jruby?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) which also provides a headless webkit driver for capybara, but does not rely on any native extensions. Instead, it uses [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) to drive the tests. According to the README jruby is supported.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long shot but have you tried `gem 'spoon'` in your `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to get capybara-webkit working with JRuby. I have had success using MRI for my development/TDD cycles and switching to JRuby (using RVM) to make sure everything still runs. When I run my JRuby features (cucumber), I just use selenium for testing javascript. I have a bit of setup code that looks similar to this in features/support/setup.rb:

```
Before do
  if running_in_jruby
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
  else
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  end
end
```

This is specific to cucumber of course, although you should be able to do something similar with rspec. I've found that MRI is quite a bit faster at running my tests due to the faster startup time vs. Java. I'll run my features/specs many times during the development of a feature, and then before I check in I'll switch to JRuby and run the tests just once.